# CSS File missing whenever I run watir-webdriver

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, watir

I am trying to learn how to use watir-webdriver in ruby.  Whenever I run my watir-webdriver scripts on sites I am QA'ing, I encounter certain pages with missing CSS Files.  This only occurs with watir-webdriver. When I test manually or in selenium-webdriver, everything works fine.  The missing CSS is essential for the functionality for the site and ends up breaking my scripts.  Is this a known issue (I didn't find anything googling around) and is there a known workaround?

### Update

Anything which was removed from this sample of code was either stuff I could not Post (URL's and Titles) or actions such as checking boxes or filling out text fields.

Watir Edited Code (Fluff Removed)

```
 b = Watir::Browser.start "URL"  
 b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30  
 b.link(:text => 'Sign Up').click  
 #Fill Up Sign Up Forms  
 b.div(:id => "btn_continue").click  
 #This is where the the missing CSS problem occurs most frequently when this page loads it will be missing CSS and break the script  
 puts b.title = "Title"  
 b.buttion(:value => "Verify My Identity").click
```

Selenium WD Edited Code (Fluff Removed)

```
 driver.get "URL"  
 assert_equal "Title", @driver.title  
 sleep(5)  
 @driver.find_element(:id, "signup").click  
 #Fill Up Sign Up Forms  
 @driver.find_element(:id, "btn_continue").click  
 sleep(30)  
 #No Missing CSS like there is in Watir  
 assert_equal "Title", @driver.title  
 @driver.find_element(:css, "input.orange").click
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the failure?  For example, a link to the site + watir code (if allowed) or the minimum amount of HTML to reproduce the issue (along with watir code and stacktrace)?  Just edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Watir-webdriver is mostly just an API wrapper around selenium-webdriver, which makes it surprising that selenium works but watir does not. Did you try different browsers? It might help narrow the problem done.

Comment: @orde I can't put up the links, however I hope this code will be of help.

Comment: @JustinKo I have not tried different browsers, I will try that out.  All of my current scripts run only in ff since I am still relatively new to Selenium and Watir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try disabling caching. It solved a [similar issue](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/124tqkh7wz/css-and-js-not-loaded-in-ff-when-executing-my-tests) for others, but it still seems fishy that selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver would behave differently.

```rb
require 'watir-webdriver'

require 'selenium-webdriver'
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.cache.disk.enable'] = false

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Comment: This worked like charm.  If you don't mind could you answer a follow up question?  I though selenium launched a fresh instance of FF, if Watir does the same (I think it does) why would there be an issue with the cache?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to that. Watir-webdriver is just calling the selenium-webdriver methods - ie in theory, they should behave exactly the same.